# Problem with launching jupyter notebook suddenly on Mac terminal.It was working fine

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Last login: Sat Mar 16 11:57:39 on ttys000

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/jpeg-turbo/bin:$PATH"
MyLap-MBP:~ hello$ /anaconda2/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda2/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tornado import iostream
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tornado.netutil import ssl_wrap_socket, _client_ssl_defaults, _server_ssl_defaults
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 44, in <module>
    _client_ssl_defaults = ssl.create_default_context(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_default_context'
logout
Saving session...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: I had a similar problem. `pip install tornado==4.5` resolved this for me.

Comment: Did u try this? Worked for u?